# Displaying only last row in datagridview from sharepoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint, datagridview, sharepoint-2010

I have written the following code for retrieving the data from sharepoint list and displaying it onto the datagridview, but it's displaying only the last row of sharepoint list. I am not understanding what the problem is. Also, I need selected title name and it's related data to be displayed in datagridview.

```
if (items2["Title"].ToString() == items["Name"].ToString())
{
    if (aaitems1.Count > 0)
    {
        if (items2["Title"] != null)
        {                 
            FieldUserValue ICDe_No = items2["ICDe_x0020_No"] as FieldUserValue;
            FieldUserValue smt1 = items2["SMT"] as FieldUserValue;
            FieldUserValue object_code = items2["Object_Code"] as FieldUserValue;
            FieldUserValue interface_name = items2["Interface_x0020_Name"] as FieldUserValue;
            FieldUserValue dre_name = items2["DRE_x0020_Name"] as FieldUserValue;

            if (items2["ICDe_x0020_No"] != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["ICDe_No"].Value = items2["ICDe_x0020_No"].ToString();
                //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(icdeno);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["ICDe_No"].Value = "";
            }

            if (items2["SMT"] != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["SMT"].Value = items2["SMT"].ToString();
               // dataGridView1.Rows.Add(smt);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["SMT"].Value = "";
            }

            if (items2["Object_Code"] != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Object_Code"].Value = items2["Object_Code"].ToString();
                //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(objectcode);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Object_Code"].Value = "";
            }

            if (items2["Interface_x0020_Name"] != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Interface_Name"].Value = items2["Interface_x0020_Name"].ToString();
                //dataGridView1.Rows.Add(interfacename);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["Interface_Name"].Value = "";
            }

            if (items2["DRE_x0020_Name"] != null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["DRE_Name"].Value = items2["DRE_x0020_Name"].ToString();
               // dataGridView1.Rows.Add(drename);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[index].Cells["DRE_Name"].Value = "";                   
            }

            //dataGridView1.DataSource = items2["Title"].ToString();
            // dataGridView1.Show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // label2.Text = "Your components cannot be displayed";
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if we don't have the full code, i would say that you are not incrementing the index variable.

Regards.